# Magento add Template to Widget and pass variables

Tags: php, magento, widget

I've build my first Magento Widget. 
Now in the /Block/MyBlock.php 
I would like to call a *.phtml template and hand over some variables, given in the widget.

I managed to call my template within the /Block/MyBlock.php with

```
    protected function _toHtml() {
        return Mage::getSingleton('core/layout')->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('webmasterei/Header.phtml')->toHtml();
        $brand_header_logo = $this->getData('brand_header_logo');
        $this->setData('logo',$brand_header_logo);
}
```

Now I want to `echo $brand_header_logo` within the Header.phtml. How do I do that? Is the template actually in the right place or should I make that with this?

```
<template>
                <required>1</required>
                <visible>0</visible>
                <label>Template</label>
                <type>select</type>
                <value>path/to/template/template.phtml</value>

            </template>
```

How do I hand over the variables from the MyBlock.php in this case?

I tried now in the /template/Module/template.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->logo ?>
```

As layed out before but that doesn't work. I think I'm missing the connection here.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variable to your template with:

```
 ->setData('logo', $brand_header_logo)
```

Then in your template file:

```
 <?php echo $this->logo ?>
```

Comment: thanks for the input. Could you expand your explanaition a little more. I don't get it. What is respnsible for the connection of the templates? Which way to use? Am I in the right function like this? I'd aktually like to use the template from widget.xml. Could you throw a short example how to call it and how to output the variable within. Thanks